# any help or idea on how to implement the timer functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following code in react native,

```
  let pub='';
  let x= '';
    // global variables
     
    setInterval(() = {
     const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('users');//read data from async storage
     pub = JSON.parse(value);
     for (let i = 0; i < pub.length; i++) {
         x = pub[i].id;
         console.log('value of id >>', x);  // the value of x is printed every 30 secs, //if there are 3 values of x as 1,2,3    
//I want 1 to be printed first 30 secs ,2 next 30 sec, 3 to be priint next
 30sec and again goback to 1 and so on..how to do ?
    
     },30000)
```

I want the value of the id to be printed every 30 seconds incrementing

for example,
if x has 1,2,3.
I want 1st 30 sec 1 to be printed,
I want 2nd 30 sec 2 to be printed,
3rd 30 sec 3 to be printed and repeat the same ...

Comment: needs more information like the component code and so on. It's better if you can provide https://codesandbox.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the `for` loop. The interval with an incrementing index takes care of that. Here's an example that will repeat or stop the interval once it's reached it's length - it's set for 3 seconds here in the example. Also note the fix in your arrow function `() = {` should be `() => {`.

```js
//const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('users'); 
//pub = JSON.parse(value);
let pub = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4}, {'id': 7}, {'id': "F"}];
let id_index = 0,
  repeat = true
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  x = pub[id_index].id;
  console.log('value of id >>', x);
  if (id_index++ >= pub.length-1) {
    if (repeat) id_index = 0; //reset
    else clearInterval(interval)
  }

}, 500)

// just in case you have to stop
// clearInterval(interval)
```

Comment: @userrr - fixed. my bad. it should test for `>= pub.length-1` - answer updated

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below

```
const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('users');//read data from async storage
pub = JSON.parse(value);

if(!Array.isArray(pub))
  return; 

let i =0;
setInterval(() => { 
                   console.log('value of id >>', pub[i].id); 
                   i++;
                 },30000)
```

Comment: @Kinglish ohh sorry that my bad :)